# Need help with div creation

Tags: dojo

I need to create something similar what we have in desktop app but it need to be on site.[image]

All theses panels are objects in Java with properties type, number and name. I have same objects in my array ( json format and I create array of objects with dojo.declare). How to create for one object this thing 
[image]

How to create this ? Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 2):

```
var container = dojo.create("div");

dojo.forEach(array, function(obj) {
    var wrapper = dojo.create("div", null, container);
    var topline = dojo.create("div", null, wrapper);
    var bottomline = dojo.create("div", {"class":"IDField"}, wrapper);
    var leftcell = dojo.create("div", {"class":"LetterField"}, topline);
    var rightcell = dojo.create("div", {"class":"NumField " + (obj.NumField === 0 ? "Gray" : "Yellow")}, topline);

    leftcell.innerText = obj.......
         :
         :
});
```